Error While Running sugar upload in NEW SOLANA token creation
While running sugar upload command from my cli, I see below error-
sugar upload
[1/4]   Loading assets

 Error running command (re-run needed): Couldn't find an image filename at index 0.

I have two files inside assets directory- 0.json and IMAGE1.png
below is my 0.json-
{
  "name": "TokenName",
  "symbol": "SYMBOL",
  "description": "Description here",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 0,
  "image": "IMAGE1.png",
  "external_url": "http://websitedns.com/",
  "attributes": [
    { "trait_type": "Category", "value": "Utility Token" },
    { "trait_type": "Website", "value": "http://websitedns.com/" },
    { "trait_type": "Telegram", "value": "http://websitedns.com/" },
    { "trait_type": "Twitter", "value": "http://websitedns.com/" }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "IMAGE1.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image"
  }
}

What wrong am I doing here? Can you please suggest?
below is the config.json-
{
  "price": 0,
  "number": 1,
  "symbol": "AMT",
  "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 0,
  "isMutable": true,
  "isSequential": false,
  "uploadMethod": "bundlr",
  "ruleSet": null,
  "creators": [
    {
      "address": "CREATOR_ADDRESS_HERE",
      "share": 100
    }
  ]
}

Below is my sugar version-
sugar-cli 2.6.0
sugar.log-
{"v":0,"name":"sugar","msg":"Lend me some sugar, I am your neighbor.","level":30,"hostname":"instance","pid":92092,"time":"2024-11-28T15:48:37.624117941Z","target":"sugar","line":123,"file":"/root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sugar-cli-2.6.0/src/main.rs"}
{"v":0,"name":"sugar","msg":"**Couldn't find an image filename at index 0.**","level":50,"hostname":"instance","pid":92092,"time":"2024-11-28T15:48:37.626770027Z","target":"sugar_cli::upload::assets","line":196,"file":"/root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sugar-cli-2.6.0/src/upload/assets.rs"}
7d22bba15001f/sugar-cli-2.6.0/src/cache.rs"}
root@instance:~/token_creation/metadata#

I already have files with permissions here-
root@instance:~/token_creation/metadata# ls -altr
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 28 14:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  291 Nov 28 14:32 config.json
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 28 14:43 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Nov 28 15:38 assets
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  670 Nov 28 15:48 sugar.log

root@instance:~/token_creation/metadata# ls -altr assets/
total 104
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 93125 Nov 28 14:34 IMAGE1.png
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Nov 28 14:43 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   637 Nov 28 15:36 0.json
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Nov 28 15:38 .
root@instance:~/token_creation/metadata#


This question is about the practicalities of a cryptocurrency. That's off-topic. We focus on cryptography, not it's applications or code using it. See this meta for more. I migrated the Q to Solana-se, currently in beta. Followup there.
